# INLINE XSLT not showing up in browser

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hello have recently inherited a report at work from someone who left suddenly. they didn't leave me any documentation so I'm stuck sort of figuring it out.

My issue is the report is XML/XSLT and I have very little in the way of experience with XSLT.  further it seems to be that the XSLT and XML are within the same file.

Because of the sensitive nature of the work I can't post the actual example which I know is going to limit the help I can get. but below is an example of what I am working with.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<root>
  <AllowedEntity>Occurrence</AllowedEntity>
  <OutputType>html</OutputType>
  <ReportXSL>
    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:nicheFunctions="urn:nicheFunctions" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
                <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
                <xsl:template match="/">
                    <xsl:element name="HTML">
                        <xsl:variable name="ReportTitle">stuff<xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:element name="title"><xsl:value-of select="$ReportTitle" /></xsl:element>

                        <!-- Insert the style class declarations -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="StyleClasses" />

                        <xsl:element name="BODY">
                            <!-- Insert the title-->
                            <xsl:call-template name="Title">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Text" select="$ReportTitle" />
                            </xsl:call-template>


                </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>]]>
  </ReportXSL>
</root>
```

Now I cut a lot of code out here but after all the pre-amble my first thing Is I would like to open this file up and view it so I know what it is supposed to look like so I can trace back through the code and figure out how it's doing it.  but when I open this in any browser it just displays it all as the XML and XSLT.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well what do you expect it to show up as? The browser doesn't interpret XSLT, that's done by an XSLT processor.

Comment: It's strange to embed a stylesheet in a source document in this way, but so long as there's code somewhere that understands this is what's being done, it's not actually wrong. You just need to find the code that's reading this input, extracting the stylesheet, and causing it to be executed. It certainly won't happen automatically.